# Japanese keyboard's height

Tags: iphone, keyboard, height

I want to scroll up my form to let the keyboard under the UITextField. It works for English keyboard, but when i change to Japanese keyboard, my form only scroll up little. I debug and find out that the height of keyboard for two cases is difference.

I do as following

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
            selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
            name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

   [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
             selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
             name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}

- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

    CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;

    NSLog(@"kbSize.height=%0.1f", kbSize.height);

    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, kbSize.height, 0.0);
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, activeField.frame.origin) )
    {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, activeField.frame.origin.y-kbSize.height);
        [scrollView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillBeHidden:(NSNotification*)aNotification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    scrollView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    scrollView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}

- (void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = textField;
}

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    activeField = nil;
}
```

And here is the result of info:

1. For ENGLISH keyboard:   kbSize.height=216.0
2. For JAPANESE keyboard:   kbSize.height=252.0

Is there anyone got this case? And can somebody help me to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardModeChange:) name:UITextInputCurrentInputModeDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

Comment: Could you provide a little more context for your answer? It might help to explain what you're getting at here.